# Rails has_one association is saved even after the transaction is rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading rails 3 app to rails 5 version. I have has_one and belongs_to association. I am saving records in transaction block. in rails 5 i have observed that in case if transaction is rollbacked then null data is getting inserted into the "tasks" table. In case of rails 3 this is not happening. is this expected behaviour in rails 5 ? i don't want to break existing functionality so is there way to retain rails 3 behaviour in rails 5?

below is sample code to to produce this issue.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :task
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    validates_presence_of :name
end

student = Student.first
student.name = nil
def student.testing
 begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   t = Task.new
   t.name = 'ddd'
   t.student = self
   t.save!
   puts "raising exception"
   raise "exception"
  end
 rescue => e
 end
end
student.testing
student.save!
```

Comment: Using `def` to define the method on a single instance of the model is pretty weird. I would move the method into the class definition to make this code less confusing to readers. Using `rescue` without a specific error class is also an example of the pokemon exception handling anti-pattern and a very likely explanation of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are *has_one association is saved* and *null data is getting inserted into the belongs_to table*? Please update your question with understandable example

Comment: @max what i don't understand is why this is not happening when i am changes relation from has_one to has_many :tasks

Comment: @Max The code i have posted is just to reproduce error.. actual code is different.. i want to know why null data is not getting inserted when i am changing relation to has_many

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by "null data is inserted"? What exactly is null and saved into the database, the student (which cannot be null, because it seems to be valid). Or `student.task` (which makes totally sense because the assigned task was rolled back on the DB level)? And what was different with Rails 3, if it didn't write the null tasks, what value did it write instead? It is not clear to me what you expected output would look like.

Answer (score 1):

From that example, I can only figure out one issue - and it is with how rails detects `inverse_of` for associations.

### Has one

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :task, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
>> Task.reflect_on_association(:student).inverse_of.name
=> :task
```

Because inverse_of is set, when you assign `student` to `task.student` the inverse is also assigned - `student.task`:

```rb
student = Student.first

student.association(:task).target    #=> nil
Task.new(student: student)
student.association(:task).target    #=> #<Task:0x00007f2333a18ad0 id: nil, name: nil, student_id: 2>

# something to save ---------------------^
student.save!

# INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "student_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", nil], ["student_id", 2]]
```

It doesn't matter if you rolled back the task transaction, object is still assigned to `student.task`, and new associations get saved when parent is saved. This does the exact same thing:

```rb
student = Student.first
Task.transaction do
  Task.create!(student: student)
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
student.save!

TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Task Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "student_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", nil], ["student_id", 2]]
TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
Task Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "student_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", nil], ["student_id", 2]]
TRANSACTION (9.8ms)  commit transaction
```

##### without inverse

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, inverse_of: false
end
```

Behaves the same as `has_many`:

```rb
Task.reflect_on_association(:student).inverse_of #=> nil
student = Student.first

student.association(:task).target    #=> nil
Task.new(student: student)
student.association(:task).target    #=> nil

# nothing to save -----------------------^
student.save!
```

### Has many

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```rb
Task.reflect_on_association(:student).inverse_of # => nil
student = Student.first

student.association(:tasks).target    #=> []
Task.new(student: student)
student.association(:tasks).target    #=> []

# nothing to save ------------------------^
student.save!
```

##### with inverse

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, inverse_of: :tasks
end
```

```rb
Task.reflect_on_association(:student).inverse_of.name #=> :tasks
student = Student.first

student.association(:tasks).target    #=> []
Task.new(student: student)
student.association(:tasks).target    #=> [#<Task:0x00007f007d82b2c8 id: nil, name: nil, student_id: 2>]

# something to save ----------------------^
student.save!

# INSERT INTO "tasks" ("name", "student_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", nil], ["student_id", 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "the belongs_to table" is `students` (why don't you just say "students" or "tasks" here?) then yes, the code you show should result in "null data" being saved to the `students` table.

Not sure why you would think the rolled back transaction block around the `Task#save!` code would impact the `student.name = nil; student.save!` code?

Comment: They why null record is not inserted when i am changing relationship to has_many ? why this null record is getting inserted only in case of has_one ?

Comment: Your question was about Rails 3 vs 5, if you meant to ask something about `has_one` vs `has_many` then you need to update your question so we can see what you're talking about.